# Reordering the alphabet to come in first in lexicographical order in fastest way

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, trie, alphabetical-sort

> Consider we have a list with names of people which no two of them are the same. The maximum size of the list is:
>
> [image]
>
> Now the goal is to find out how many names (and which ones!)can come first in lexicographical ordering if we changed the English alphabets order!
>   for instance if the list is:
>
> ```
> ha haa st
> ```
>
> then with changing the alphabet we can bring *ha* and *st* in first place but no matter how we change it *haa* will always come after *ha*, so two names can come first.

Of course there is a brute force way to found out the answers but that need to check all 26! possible orders of alphabet for each word! Since the time limit on this problem is **1 second** then I think an algorithm with O(nlogn) or lower would do find. However I don't know how to approach the problem. I thing using **trie** would be helpful (since i encountered the problem when I was learning data structures!) but may be graph algorithms could also help.

How can I find the right algorithm and approach to this problem and how to implement it in code?

Comment: The expectations we apply to homework problems apply to such challenge problems as well.  Simply dropping the problem statement on us, with no demonstrated effort, and asking for a solution, is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Prune well I don't know what to do. I'm pretty sure I should use trie for this job but I couldn't find any help on the internet. What should some one do when he has no idea what to do and no one helps out?

Comment: It is generally our experience that educators do not set problems that students would have no hope of solving. Thus it is likely that one of your lectures or one of your set texts would have the answer, and you have been taught the relevant material. It is possible that you would get a hint in the comments, but you may find it more useful to go to a revision session or consult with your course supervisor.

Comment: A trie will let you eliminate `haa` above, but doesn't let you eliminate `ahh` out of `aha hah ahh`.

Comment: @FarzinNasiri  What is one to do?  Perhaps post to an open-ended help site, rather than StackOverflow.  First, though, I'd contact the human resources for your class (instructor, tutor, etc.) for wider help in problem analysis and appropriate solution techniques.  "I don't know how to solve this" is not a Stack Overflow issue.

Answer (score 1):

Let `w` be that first word

1. If we change alphabet letters, the first word keeps its length. Any name which can come in first place **must** be of length ...length(w).
2. Let `L` be the candidate words above. All the names are different as per initial formulation, so `L` is also made of unique names.

Only name in `L` is solution. Any name in `L` is solution. The answer to your problem is `L`'s size.

---

tldr: count all the words of length length(`w`)